# getting data from multiple models through a textbox value in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models and below are the schemas of these models:

```
    user's model schema:
    id | First_Name
    1  | abc       
    2  | xyz

profession's model schema:
id | UserID | Designation
1  | 1      | Lead
2  | 1      | software engineer
3  | 2      | Lead
```

And I have textbox where I enter "designation" of the user in the search page, and when I enter "Lead" in the "designation" textbox and click on submit button, then it gave me the `user's First_Name and Designation` 
whose designation is equal to "lead". And below is my view page code:

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td align="center" style="vertical-align:top;">
            <h2 style="color:Black; font-size: x-large;">Specs</h2>               
         <table>
             <tr>
               <td align="center">
                  <input type="text" name="tf_Designation" Style="text-align: left;" BackColor="#e5e5e5" Width="180px" ForeColor="Gray" Font-Size="Large">
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <div class="button">
                    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="buttonSearch">
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <div class="button">
                      <%= button_to "Back", '/default', { method: :get, :class => "buttonBack" } %>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Below are the models:

```
Profession's model:
class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :UserID, presence: true
end
User's model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :professions, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And I am using below for doing it:

```
  def search 
    if ( !params[:tf_Designation].blank? or params[:tf_Designation] !="" )
      @user_designation = User.joins(:professions).where(:professions => {:Designation => params[:tf_Designation].strip}).collect(&:First_Name)

    end     
  render 'search'
  end
```

But it gave me error below:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: professions.user_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "professions" ON "professions"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "professions"."Designation" = 'Lead'
```

But in the above error its uses `"professions"."user_id"` but in my professions model i am using `"UserID"` instead of `"user_id"`. So How do I changed `"user_id"` to `"UserID"` Kindly, suggest me, waiting for your reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
profession = Profession.find(:all,:conditions=>["designation=?",params[:search_key]], :select=>"user_id")

pro_users = User.find profession

first_names = pro_users.map(&:first_name)
```

`params[:search_key]` will have the designation item searched.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller use following code :

```
@first_names = User.joins(:professions).where(:professions => {:designation => params[:tf_Designation].strip}).collect(&:first_name)
```

Comment: It should be returning the first name of all the users with the desired designation.
Can you tell me what do you get in parameters and what is the output of this query.

Comment: Error: {SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: professions.user_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "professions" ON "professions"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "professions"."Designation" = 'Lead'} But in professions table foreign_key column is "UserID" not "user_id", and where i change this.

Comment: what have you mentioned in the model.
Can you try mentioning the foreigh key in the User model as following :
has_many :professions, class_name: "Profession", foreign_key: "UserID"